# How boot custom ISO within Rescue Mode (or not) in a OVH VPS

Tags: linux, iso-image, vps, rescue

I need to boot a custom ISO in OVH VPS, but i don't know how, the iso I need to boot is from FreePBX.
Right now the VPS is in Rescue Mode.

So, how to boot the FreePBX ISO Image in my OVH VPS if already installed an distro like CentOS 6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update Nov 2022**:

You need to install `qemu` inside the Rescue System to mount a custom `iso` in a VPS that does not support it natively. The `iso` image will need to be smaller than available RAM.

Most Rescue systems are Debian based so the following should generally work anywhere including on systems **without** nested virtualization (i.e no `/dev/kvm`):

```
# Example with 4GB of RAM in the qemu commands

apt update
apt install qemu qemu-system-x86 --no-install-recommends

# may have more tmpfs space on Rescue systems that run
# from a small partition.
cd /dev/shm

# netboot (choice of many live iso's) 
wget http://boot.netboot.xyz/ipxe/netboot.xyz.iso
MYISO=/dev/shm/netboot.xyz.iso

# alternatively ubuntu server
wget https://releases.ubuntu.com/22.04.1/ubuntu-22.04.1-live-server-amd64.iso
MYISO=/dev/shm/ubuntu-22.04.1-live-server-amd64.iso

#VNC (always works)
qemu-system-x86_64 -netdev type=user,id=mynet0 -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=mynet0 -m 4G -no-kvm -drive file=/dev/vdb,format=raw,if=virtio -vga std -k en-gb -daemonize -cdrom $MYISO -boot d -vnc :1

# SPICE (faster || less reliable)
qemu-system-x86_64 -netdev type=user,id=mynet0 -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=mynet0 -m 4G -no-kvm -drive file=/dev/vdb,format=raw,if=virtio -vga qxl -spice port=5900,addr=127.0.0.1,disable-ticketing -daemonize -cdrom $MYISO -boot d
```

---

If `modprobe kvm` creates `/dev/kvm` in your Rescue system then for better performance `-no-kvm` above can be replaced with `-enable-kvm`.

For detailed options:

- `man qemu` or see the [Debian Man Page](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/qemu-system-x86/qemu-system-x86_64.1.en.html)